# Expand function around point where function is zero

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a function $f(x)$ that I want to expand around the point where $f(x)=0$, but finding this point is difficult. What is the general way to expand around the point $f(x)=0$ without actually knowing what that point is? I'm sure it's something along the lines of a Taylor Series but I can't quite figure it out.